# How to iterate though multiple .csv files, where each file should be read in by chunks because of lack of RAM in r

Tags: r, large-files

I have a large dataset that consists of multiple .csv files. Each .csv file is about 5-10 GB, which is too heavy and time-consuming for my computer's RAM. To solve the problem I thought of making chunks (let's say Chunk = 1000), but when inserting it in my code it only iterates through the first 1,000 rows. Here is an example of the code:

```
# Trying to make a for loop iteration through multiple files
## Attempt - with CON. (Does not iterate for each chunk through the files)
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

file_paths <- fs::dir_ls("path/to/folder")
file_contents <- list()
chunkSize = 1000

for(i in seq_along(file_paths)){
  # Open a connection to file i in readable format
  con = file(file_paths[[i]], "r")
  # Assign to empty list, and read in data in chunks
  file_contents[[i]] <- read.csv(con, nrows = chunkSize)
}
close(con)

# set name to each of the file paths
file_contents <- set_names(file_contents, file_paths)
```

Comment: You only read in the first 1000 lines of each file.  You need an inner loop to read the subsequernt chunks of each file until you reach the end of the file.  Also, your `close(con)` should probably be within the (outer) loop.

Comment: Does this help you? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nHsfkYZSUA

Comment: I don't understand.  `file_paths[i]` is a single element of a vector.  of course its length is 1.  What do you get from `length(file_paths)`?